# Pagination echoed by paginate_links() not showing in page.php

Tags: wordpress, pagination

A pagination echoed by paginate_links() shows only in category.php and doesn't show in page.php .

```
if(is_page('news')):
 $catquery = new WP_Query('category_name="news"');
 echo '<div class="outer">';
 if($catquery->have_posts()) : while($catquery->have_posts()) : $catquery->the_post(); ?>
<a class="wrapper news-item" href="<?php echo get_field('permalink'); ?>">
<div data-aos="fade-up" class="inner" style="background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.2),rgba(0,0,0,0.2)), url('<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>')">
<?php the_content(); ?>
</div>
</a>
<?php
 endwhile; 
 wp_reset_postdata();
 endif;                                 echo '</div>';

<div class="pagination" data-aos="fade-up">
<?php
 $total_pages = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
 $current_page = max(0, get_query_var('paged'));
                                    echo paginate_links(array(                                   
 'base' => get_pagenum_link().'%_%',
 'format'             => '?paged=%#%',
 'show_all'           => false,
 'current' => $current_page,
 'total' => $total_pages,
 'end_size'           => 2,
 'mid_size'           => 2,
 'prev_next'          => true,
 'prev_text'          => __('« Previous'),
 'next_text'          => __('Next »'),
 'type'               => 'plain',
 'add_args'           => false,
 'add_fragment'       => '',
 'before_page_number' => '',
 'after_page_number'  => ''                                 ));
?>
</div>
```

No error message shows in the post archive page. Please help me display a pagination using paginate_links() in page.php

Answer (score 0):

You have to add below line -

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
```

above your this line of code -

```
$catquery = new WP_Query('category_name="news"');
```

also, you need to replace this -

```
$catquery = new WP_Query('category_name="news"');
```

with this below code -

```
$catquery = new WP_Query(array(
    'category_name' => 'news',
    'paged' => $paged
    ));
```

Comment: Thank you. Replacing $total_pages = $wp_query->max_num_pages; with $total_pages = $catquery->max_num_pages; indeed let the pagination links show up. On the downside, clicking any of the links only shows the first page of the archive. Is there something to be added/changed in the parameter of paginate_links()?

Comment: Thank you, that solved the problem!

Does this line of the code indicate if the archive of posts is paginated, get the paginated archive?:
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

Comment: By using this code you get current page number for pagination.